# React: How to call dispatch if the useSelector is empty using useEffect without causing the browser to crash?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Question, I have this component that will display list of data coming from my backend. I'm using redux for my state management. So, I'm using useEffect to execute the if statement to find out if this useSelector is empty, if yes a redux action will be dispatch. But my problem is what if the query is empty? The use effect that will execute the dispatch will be rendered again and again causing the browser to crash. How can I find out if the query is empty so that the if statement in inside useEffect will not execute.

**Sample Code**

```
const [listdata, setListData] = useState(); 

const dataList = useSelector((state) => state.dataList);
const { data } = useSelector;

useEffect(() => {
    if (data === undefined || data .length === 0) {
dispatch(getDataList());
}else{
setListData(data);
}
  }, [dispatch, data ]);
```